# Django request.body always printing nonsense result (b'')

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django , I started working on an existing Vuejs/Django project to easily understand how things are working .
I wrote a new specific view in views.js

```
def hello(request):
   print(req.body)
   return HttpResponse('hello')
```

Then in urls.py I added the following:

```
path('hello/',views.hello,name='hello')
```

At first I tried sending a plain/text , but the print function shows the following

> b''

I tried printing request.data but it says

> WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

I tried sending a JSON and using the following :

> body_string = request.body.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
>
> data = json.loads(body_string)

Result :

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)Expecting value:

or:

> data = json.loads(request.data.get('_content'))

Result:

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

none of that seems to be working .
The app I am working on seems to be working fine but it has no specific URL that's way I am stuck as I have no example , even here I couldn't find anything that helps.

Comment: A request often has no body. So it is correct. What you see is a *bytestring* that is empty. Normally in a POST request, the data is put in the *header*. You can access it with `request.POST`, or all headers with `request.META`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Willem , and how do I write a specific POST URL in django ? as the "hello" view is a made for GET request by default.

Comment: @mascor No matter what method you're using, the request comes to /hello will be served by home view. So, to identify the request is GET or POST, you could use `request.method == 'POST'` or `request.method == 'GET'`. You can also use class-based view to separate that.